# D3 Apply projection to d3-tip tooltip

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a map of the US, with cities plotted.  I'm trying to use d3-tip to provide tooltips to my cities on hover.  The problem I'm running into is that d3-tip isn't accounting for the projection, and I'm not sure how to apply it.

The projection I'm using:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .scale(150)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 1.5]);
```

I apply it to my circle elements by the following:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
  return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0];
})
.attr("cy", function(d) {
  return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1];
})
```

Problem is d3-tip doesn't seem to take x and y attributes, it grabs them from the node issuing the event and doesn't seem to account for it having the projection applied; which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do tooltips with d3 by appending a div with absolute positioning and hiding it in the body.

Then on mousing over an element, I move the div to the location of the mouse pointer and unhide it.  I then hide the div once the mouseout event occurs.

This allows me to control X and Y as well as the styling and text of the tooltip.

Here's a great example: https://gist.github.com/biovisualize/1016860